# how to divide pos and negative values from one column to value from another column and add the result in new column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a large text file and want to divide values from column7 (BETA) to column 8 (SE), and make a new column at the end of table with the results (column 11). The issue is some values in column 7 passed the zero and are negative.

```
SNP         CHR BP         A1 AX A1_FREQ BETA        SE         P          OBS_CT
rs10875231  1   100000012  T  G  0.405   -0.0456807  0.02260471 0.04335677 4400
rs6678176   1   100000827  C  T  0.383   0.02553138  0.02287662 0.2645817  4400
rs78590530  1   100000948  A  G  0.016   0.171376    0.08757958 0.05035017 4400
rs149636485 1   100001060  A  G  0.004   -0.03363731 0.1819208  0.8529224  4400
rs116216467 1   100001233  C  T  0.043   -0.06690947 0.05683414 0.238941   4400
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Explain **in your question** why some values being negative is an issue.

Comment: thanks...so i tried simple command that indicates negative value as error or may be because values are less than 1 ;           awk '{$11 = $7 / $8}1'  test1.txt  column -t > test1b.txt
                       awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=test1.txt FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted

Comment: @motor30 please use the [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/748046/edit) function to update your question with the code you tried and the errors you received. Please also ensure to add an example of the desired output.

Comment: @motor30 dividing by zero has nothing to do with negative values, and that error would occur if $8 was zero, not $7. You haven't shown us any zeros in $8 in your input, nor posted the expected output, so we'd just be guessing at what you want to output when that occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the first line, which contains non-numeric strings. You can exclude it like this:

```
NR!=1 { $11 = $7/$8 }
1
```

Now, if you think that you might have a zero in column 8, you need to check that $8 is non-zero. You can add a condition to the pattern:

```
NR!=1 && $8!=0 { $11 = $7/$8 }
1
```

Alternatively, put an `if` in the action:

```
{ if (NR!=1 && $8!=0) $11 = $7/$8; print }
```

I don't see why negative values are a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "SNP         CHR BP         A1 AX A1_FREQ BETA        SE         P          OBS_CT"}NR>1{$11=$7-$8;print $0}' filename


output

SNP         CHR BP         A1 AX A1_FREQ BETA        SE         P          OBS_CT
rs10875231 1 100000012 T G 0.405 -0.0456807 0.02260471 0.04335677 4400 -0.0682854
rs6678176 1 100000827 C T 0.383 0.02553138 0.02287662 0.2645817 4400 0.00265476
rs78590530 1 100000948 A G 0.016 0.171376 0.08757958 0.05035017 4400 0.0837964
rs149636485 1 100001060 A G 0.004 -0.03363731 0.1819208 0.8529224 4400 -0.215558
rs116216467 1 100001233 C T 0.043 -0.06690947 0.05683414 0.238941 4400 -0.123744
```